# Protractor, Firefox, Windows Authentication, LastPass

Tags: firefox, protractor

I'm trying to use Protractor with a site that has windows authentication enabled.  I can use Chrome with the site by passing the credentials in the URL (http://username:password@server.url/), but for Firefox I run into trouble. It prompts for username and password.

In Firefox's about:config I have set 'browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled' to false, as per other internet searches, however I still continue to get prompted when I try to pass the credentials in the URL browser.get().

I had an outside the box idea of using LastPass in Firefox to AutoLogin and that does work when I now navigate to the URL.  But when I run Protractor it opens a shell like version of Firefox with no plugins.

Is there a way to enable plugins for Protractor when it runs Firefox?

I also tried the following to create a profile and verified that the setting for the malware config line was false.  I still continue to get the Windows Authentication pop-up box.

```
var Firefox = require('..\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\firefox'); 
var getFFProfile = function() { 
    var deferred = q.defer(); 
    var ffProfile = new Firefox.Profile(); 
    ffProfile.setPreference('browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled', false);
    ffProfile.encode().then(function(encodedProfile) { 
        var multiCapabilities = [{ 
            browserName: 'firefox', 
            firefox_profile : encodedProfile 
        }]; 
        deferred.resolve(multiCapabilities);
    }); 
    return deferred.promise; 
}; 
exports.config= {
    specs:['spec.js'],
    getMultiCapabilities:getFFProfile
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Firefox's about:config I have set 'browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled' to false

This is something you need to tell firefox to set when starting a new browser instance with the help of `firefox-profile` and `q` packages (also, see an example [here](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile)):

```
var FirefoxProfile = require("firefox-profile");
var q = require("q");

var makeFirefoxProfile = function(preferenceMap, specs) {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

    for (var key in preferenceMap) {
        firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
    }

    firefoxProfile.encoded(function (encodedProfile) {
        var capabilities = {
            browserName: "firefox",
            directConnect: true,
            firefox_profile: encodedProfile,
            specs: specs
        };

        deferred.resolve(capabilities);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

exports.config = {
     getMultiCapabilities: makeFirefoxProfile({"browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled": false}, ["specs/myspec.js"]),
     ...
}
```

Comment: I'm missing firefox-profile.  I will look into that and test this out later today.  Thank you so much for your swift response alecxe.

Comment: I made some changes based on above, but it's still not working for me.

Comment: My changes:
`var Firefox = require('..\\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\firefox');
var getFFProfile = function() { var deferred = q.defer(); var ffProfile = new Firefox.Profile();  ffProfile.setPreference('browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled', false); ffProfile.encode().then(function(encodedProfile) {  var multiCapabilities = [{ browserName: 'firefox', firefox_profile : encodedProfile }]; deferred.resolve(multiCapabilities); 
   }); return deferred.promise; };
exports.config={specs:['spec.js'],getMultiCapabilities:getFFProfile}`